Sampling from $SO(4)$ more uniformly than Haar?
We can sample $A$ from SO(4) by sampling orthogonal $U$ from Haar until we get a sample with positive determinant. However, resulting distribution prefers rotations close to $0$ and $\pi$, pointed out by Girko:

One way to fix this would be to take orthogonal $U$ and use two 2D rotation matrices with angles $\theta_i$ sampled uniformly from $(-\pi,\pi)$
$$A=U^T \left(\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta_1 ) & -\sin (\theta_1 ) \\
 \sin (\theta_1 ) & \cos (\theta_1 ) \\
\end{array}
\right]\oplus \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta_2 ) & -\sin (\theta_2 ) \\
 \sin (\theta_2 ) & \cos (\theta_2 ) \\
\end{array}
\right]\right) U
$$
This produces eigenvalue distribution with uniform angles


Does this measure have a name?
Which one should I use to generate random rotations in practice?

Notebook

In your second method, are you sampling $U$ according to the Haar measure?

@LPZ yes, U sampled from haar although

See How to Generate Random
Matrices from the Classical
Compact Groups page 597 bottom right algorithm.

Here are two methods to sample uniformly from $SO(n)$. In theory, they are both exact, although I don't know whether one or another is better from the perspective of numerical error. By a "Gaussian", I mean a random variable on $\mathbb{R}$ with normal distribution, mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.
(Method 1): Let $X$ be an $n \times n$ matrix of independent Gaussians and compute the $QR$ factorization $X=QR$. Then $Q$ is uniformly distributed on $SO(n)$.
(Method 2): Let $Y$ be a symmetric matrix of Gaussians, with $Y_{ij} = Y_{ji}$, but otherwise independent. Find the spectral factorization $Y = UDU^T$. Now, $U$ isn't quite well defined; $U$ is defined up to conjugating by a diagonal matrix of $(\pm 1)$'s, and which $U$ you get may depend on the internals of your numerical linear algebra package. To wipe out this dependence, flip $n$ coins and let $S$ be the diagonal matrix with $S_{ii}$ equal to $1$ or $-1$ according the $i$-th coin flip. Then report $SUS$. This will be uniformly distributed on $SO(n)$.
The proof is a little easier to write for Method 1: Look at each column $(X_{1i}\ X_{2i}\ \cdots \ X_{ni})^T$ of $X$. It is distributed according to a Gaussian on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the columns are independent of each other. So the distribution of $X$ on $n \times n$ matrices is invariant under $X \mapsto PX$ for $P \in SO(n)$. If the $QR$ factorization of $X$ is $QR$, then the $QR$ factorization of $PX$ is $(PQ)R$. So the resulting distribution on $Q$ is invariant under left multiplication, so it must be Haar measure.
The same idea works with Method 2: the distribution of $Y$ is invariant under $Y \mapsto PYP^T$, but the details are a bit more of a mess to work out.

I far as I understand, the paper I link to in the comments to the question discusses a problem with your method 1, in that it doesn't give Haar-distributed sample. The problem is that the QR-decomposition is not uniquely defined (you can negate a column of in Q and a corresponding row in R).  The implementations make arbitrary choices, and these choices are usually not uniformly distributed. This problem can be fixed by bringing the QR-decomposition into a standard form by making sure the diagonal of R is non-negative. That comes down to negating every column i of $Q$ such that $R_{i, i} < 0$.

Finally, the above may result in a negative determinant, but in that case one may just negate an arbitrary column to a positive determinant without losing Haar-distributedness.
